# Some text Missing in xlsx to text in c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I am trying to do .xlsx to text in c# asp.net with Microsoft provider connection string:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\myFolder\myExcel2007file.xlsx;
Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1";
```

Then I am getting all data but the numbers like 12345.34 are converted to 12345.
In the same string if I use IMEX=0 then numbers are converted properly but I am not getting the first two rows.

Here is the link of .xlsx file [Link](http://www.fsa.usda.gov/Internet/FSA_File/2013_fsa_acres_sep_2013.zip)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not getting the first two rows is not the IMEX option, but the HDR option:

> "HDR=Yes;" indicates that the first row contains columnnames, not
>   data. "HDR=No;" indicates the opposite.

https://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/xlsx-files/

Using the connection string below:

```
Data Source=Data Source=c:\myFolder\myExcel2007file.xlsx;
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 xml;HDR=NO;IMEX=1"
```

and SQL:

```
select * from [plant_and_fail$]
```

the result was right numeric data and the first rows:
[image]